# Problem related to means

Tags: sequences-and-series, means

I am confused on proving that

If a, b, c are 3 numbers  in harmonic progression

Then

${(a^n+c^n)  /2} >({(a+c)/2}) ^n$

I attempted like this...

Since a, b, c are in hp so

$(a+c) /2>b$

where b is the Harmonic Mean of a and c.

But what next?

Comment: What you are trying to prove does not involve $c$ at all, so the harmonic progression will not help.  Given $a,b$ you can calculate $c$ as the next element in the progression if you want.

Comment: Is the problem copied correctly?  Almost any two positive reals $a,b$ can be the first two terms of a harmonic progression.

Comment: It is not true for $n=1$, you have equality in that case.

Comment: Sorry...  now the problem is correct

Comment: Now you don't use $b$ in what you are trying to prove, so can again ignore the progression.  You need to require that $a,c \ge 0$, or $a=1,c=-2,n=3$ is a counterexample.  The $\gt$ should be $\ge$ or $a=c$ and $n=1$ are counterexamples.

Comment: I do not understand... Please prove it by induction or inequality that AM>GM>HM

Comment: Is $n$ a positive integer? Are $a,c\ge0$?

Comment: Nothing given... If you feel the question is wrong please correct the question in your answer.. But dont edit mine... As this is exactly what is given

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $a,c\ge0$ and $n$ is a positive integer, we have that $x^n$ is a [convex function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) for $x\ge0$.

For any convex function, $f$,
$$
\frac{f(a)+f(c)}2\ge f\left(\frac{a+c}2\right)
$$